# Android/Java - Images are not show correctly when i send it to the browser using a server socket

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, serversocket

I have implemented a server socket that send a file (in my case images in .jpg format) when a client do an http get request. Testing using the firefox browser (and firebug), i saw that the bytes of data are correctly sent and received. My only problem is that i don't see the image in the browser, but i saw strange chars like for example: " ÿÀ�à®�ÿÄ�¾��������������������������!1AQa"q2‘¡B#±ÁRÑbr‚3ðá’¢C$ñ²SÂc4%Òsƒ“D£³T5âÃE„”�  �!1AQaq"‘¡2ð±BÑRÁáñb’#r¢‚3CSÿÚ���?�ùIè4 " and much more. So i presume that my server sent the bytes correctly, but they aren't showed like an image. Is this right? How can i fix this?
Here there is the code that i have used for send the bytes:

```
File photoFile = new File(getHeader);
  int size2 = (int) photoFile.length();
  byte[] bytes2 = new byte[size2];
  try {
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(photoFile)); 
    buf.read(bytes2, 0, bytes2.length);
    buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.getOutputStream().write(bytes2, 0, size2);
```

Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Comment: What is `client` there?

Comment: Are you sure that you have read image file in a one short? When you perform `buf.read`, actual number of read bytes can be less than `size2`.

Comment: client is defined here:
Socket client = parent.accept();
and parent is:
ServerSocket parent = new ServerSocket();

Comment: Eugene: what do you mean with "one short" ? I pass the lenght of the image to buf.read, so i don't think that the read bytes are less...

Answer (score 0):

At the end i found that the problem not depends from my code but from the browser used. I have done some test and i noticed that:
- Mozilla Firefox doesn't show the image, but the strange characters
- Safari show correctly the image
- Chrome show correctly the image
- Opera show only strange characters

So i suggest to try various browsers if you find my same problem.

Thanks